# Jquery Countdown Timer failing to load

Tags: jquery

why is my countdown timer not working. I am using keith woods plugin. Have uploaded countdown jquery to root. http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html

CODE:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquerycd/jquery.countdown.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquerycd/jquery.countdown.js"></script>

  <style>
  defaultCountdown({until: liftoffTime});
</style>

</head>

<body>
         <script>
            var newYear = new Date(); 
newYear = new Date(newYear.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 1); 
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: newYear}); 

$('#removeCountdown').toggle(function() { 
        $(this).text('Re-attach'); 
        $('#defaultCountdown').countdown('destroy'); 
    }, 
    function() { 
        $(this).text('Remove'); 
        $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: newYear}); 
    } 
);
<div id="defaultCountdown"></div>
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors? Check your chrome or firefox console.

Comment: @DG3 no errors checked in firefox

Comment: Your CSS is not relevant - that's javascript commands you've put in there, plus, you've got the div inside your script tags.

Comment: @Archer can you please post correct version of code?

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the call to your plugin JS file after the jQuery file is called.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquerycd/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
```

This is presuming the plugin JS file exists.

Comment: I have also uploaded my own library and fails to load to as above

Comment: Please update your questions HTML. Check you have no 404s etc.

Comment: You are calling jquery.js twice and countdown.js is still above jquery.js - it needs to be below.

Comment: understand, please check revised

Comment: Put your div back with an ID of defaultCountdown. Only the CSS for that DIV was incorrect, not the div itsself

Answer (score 0):

This is just a tidied version of your code, complete with a `document.ready` block (`$(function() { ... }`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquerycd/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquerycd/jquery.countdown.css" type="text/css" />
         <script>
             $(function() {
                var newYear = new Date(); 
                newYear = new Date(newYear.getFullYear() + 1, 0, 1); 
                $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({ until: newYear }); 
                $('#removeCountdown').toggle(function() { 
                    $(this).text('Re-attach'); 
                    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown('destroy'); 
                }, 
                function() { 
                    $(this).text('Remove'); 
                    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({ until: newYear }); 
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="defaultCountdown"></div>
        <div id="removeCountdown">Remove</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've also added the countdown and toggle div to the body of the document.

Comment: thank you that worked however the css is working on it. my css is in jquerycd/jquery.countdown.css. how do i link the css sheet to the countdown time?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  The css link is in the page head, and is pointing to jquery/jquery.countdown.css.  Does that css file actually exist?

Comment: in installation it says to: Connect the countdown functionality to your divs. $(selector).countdown({until: liftoffTime});

Comment: it also has a white strip along top of counter about .3cm in width which i believe to me    $(function() { causing the issue

Comment: To initialize the countdown timer you need to attach the code to it when the document is ready.  You do that by enclosing everything in `$(function() { //code goes here })`.  That's not causing the white space that you are seeing.  Also, the code above *does* "connect the countdown functionality", as it says in the documentation.  That's the line after the new year is set.  If it is not working then give me the URL and I'll have a look at it for you.